# Hardcoded index for array access

Tags: c#

I have an array that contains data in a specific order. I usually hardcode the indexes in order to not being too messy :

```
public class MyClass
{
     private readonly string[] data = new string[DATA_LENGHT];

     internal const INDEX_NAME      = 00;
     internal const INDEX_FIRSTNAME = 01;
     internal const INDEX_CITY      = 02;
     ...
     internal const DATA_LENGHT     = XX;
}
```

But this way is borring to maintain. If I want to insert a new data say at index 0, I need to manually change all the subsequent INDEX_XXX.

I would like to use some kind of initializer but the below does not work :

```
     internal const INDEX_NAME      = i++;
     internal const INDEX_FIRSTNAME = i++;
     internal const INDEX_CITY      = i++;
```

I can also change the const to a readonly and initialize it in a static constructor but this means two lines per INDEX for initialization (does not looks good actually).

What would be a clean, simple way to do it ?

Comment: Any reason to not transform that array in normal fields exposed with normally named properties?

Comment: Is the order actually important, or is it just important because you're using an array? Can you just use actual named fields?

Comment: You could use `enum Indices : int { Name = 0, FirstName, City, ..`

Comment: I am reading the clipboard and expect a specific order for the data. I am actually transforming the array to normal fields after, but first I just have this array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer is probably to use an `enum` like the [Blorgbeard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369/blorgbeard) suggested.

```
enum Indices : int
{
    Name = 0,
    FirstName,
    City,
    //...
    Length
}
```

Another solution would be to increment the previous value.

```
internal const int INDEX_NAME       = 0;
internal const int INDEX_FIRSTNAME  = INDEX_NAME + 1;
internal const int INDEX_CITY       = INDEX_FIRSTNAME + 1;
```

Comment: Ok let's use the incremental solution event if not the perfect solution (no duplicate check, kind of messy) but does not require the cast. The enum way as the duplicate check but I don't like the syntax to use it...(personal preferences)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Dictionary to hold the index values.  This would take you back to one line per index, plus a couple extra for Dictionary init.

```
private Dictionary<string,string> _indexDictionary;

public MyClass()
{
    _indexDictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    _indexDictionary.Add("INDEX_NAME","00");
    _indexDictionary.Add("INDEX_FIRSTNAME","01");
    ...
}
```

Then you'd just pull the index values out of the dictionary:

```
var blah = data[_indexDictionary["INDEX_NAME"]]
```

Readability tradeoff is arguable and a bit more overhead than an enum, but works...

Answer (score 0):

Try using an enum for this:

```
public enum MyIndexes
{
INDEX_NAME = 0,
INDEX_FIRSTNAME,
INDEX_FIRSTNAME
}
```

You can declare a value for each entry or declare the first is whatever you'd like. If you do it like this, everything after increments by one. When you want to use it as an index in your array you can use the following:

```
(int)MyIndexes.INDEX_NAME // index 0
(int)MyIndexes.INDEX_FIRSTNAME // would be index 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a strange approach, but you may replace your constants with an enumeration, such as:

```
public enum Indices
{
   INDEX_NAME = 0,
   INDEX_FIRSTNAME,
   INDEX_CITY,
   ...
}
```

and then

```
data[(int)Indices.INDEX_NAME]
```